# How can i know max resolution support of my PC video outputs?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I am using [NP700Z5C](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/high-performance/NP700Z5C-S03UK-spec) model laptop and i want to attach 2 external screen that is 1440P and 1080P for it but i am quite unsure that this laptop can reach those resolutions. I know that many hdmi output does not support 1440P resolution.

How can i know that my pc can support those resolutions without real test (attaching screens) ?

Comment: The VGA can likely do 1440p (chip spec says Up to 2048x1536) leaving the HDMI for 1080p. Note the manual states: "Simultaneous output to all 3 (LCD + CRT + HDMI) is not supported".

Comment: @Brian Why not to use HDMI for 1440P ? It will not support it ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 1440p, usually it is the vertical resolution with a p (progressive) or i (interlaced). However if you mean 1440 × 900 then that is supported off single link DVI or HDMI. If it's N x 1440 then it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to make sure if the check the laptops manual.
Alternatively, look up the specs on the web.

In the case of your laptop you have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M. According to [the manufacturers website](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-640m/specifications) that chip has a max VGA resolution of 2048x1536. However that is just the GPU part. To display what the GPU generates you will need a RAMDAC and a good cable.

400MHz DACs are common, which would commonly limit it to any configuration using a lower than 400MHz bandwidth. E.g. 2048x1536@85 Hz (388 MHz).  However you may want to check this in the manual, and you do not want poor quality cables at these resolutions otherwise ghosting is likely.

Comment: the manufacturer websites also write "Maximum Digital Resolution : 3840 x 2160". That means i can have 1440P resolution on HDMI ?

Comment: Probably. To have maximum resolution you need: 1) A GPU which support resolution X by Y, 2) The right chip to send the calculated X by Y data out of the computer (E.g. in case of analog VGA, you need a RAMDAC. In the case of digital formats those may have other bandwidth limits. For HDMI 1.0 this bandwidth  limited you to 1920x1200@60Hz. More recent HDMI standards have higher clocks yielding higher bandwidth. (In other words, you would need to check which HDMI version is used on your laptop, which HDMI cable you use and which HDMI version the monitor uses).

Comment: I wrote probably since HDMI 1.0 would not suffice for 1440P. [the manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201210/20121028110424917/Win8_Manual_eng.pdf) does not state which [HMDI standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) is used, though it **probably** works since it is a modern laptop and HDMI 1.0 is old (It is from around 2003).